# If output of program1 exe is 0 then run another exe

Tags: windows, batch-file

Im using Windows 8 and would like to have a batch file that depends of the output of the exe file will call another exe file. So the output of the exe file is 1 or 0. It is openCV file and if the program detect some object then output is 1 if not then 0. I wrote the script but it doesn't call another program in the case of output of program 1 is 0. Any help?

Here the batch file

```
   @echo off
   for /f "delims=" %%a in ('C:\Users\myProgram1.exe -a -b -c') do if /i "%%~a"=="errorlevel" (call:dothis) 
if %errorlevel%==0 call:dothis
goto:eof

:dothis
C:\Users\myProgram2.exe
exit /b 0
```

I was able only to run the OpenCVprgram1.exe (first program), but never execute OpenCVprgram2.exe in case of output 0. Any help?

here the output of myProgram1 when run this script

```
@echo off
C:\Users\myProgram1.exe > result.txt
set DATA=<result.txt
echo %DATA%
del result.txt
```

the output in case of not detected feature is 0 . As shown in this screenshot
[image: Output of program 1 is 0]

In case of detected feature is 1 as shown in this image
[image: Output of program1 is 1]

Comment: please give us an example output of ' OpenCVprgram1.exe'. Please check your code. There seems to be some typos and a wrangeled syntax.

Comment: That "batch file" has bad syntax. Post the real code.

Comment: what do you think, `%output%` contains? Maybe you want `%%a` instead? And your syntax is still not working.

Comment: I change it and made description with scrrenshots

Comment: just a wild guess: do you need the last line of the output?

Comment: Im not sure about correct syntax.Because of that need a help. I only want to have a FOR loop to check the output of program 1. I case of 0 (means not detected object) call other program2. I need FOR loop as I have many images and would like to do the same for every image, Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes, because the last line is the ouptut of that last image, As said in the comments I have lots images store in the folder, So would like to go through every image and check it, if program1 is successful (means output 1  then go to second image, that internally will handle program 1), if for that image program 1 failed then call program 2. then move to next image. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 0):

According to the recent changes to your question and your comments, the following should be quite near to what you want.

```
REM for every file do:
for %%a in (*.*) do (   
  REM get last line [reference filename with %%a]
  for /f %%b in ('myProgram1.exe -a -b -c "%%~a"`) do set lastLine=%%b
  REM check for "0":
  if "!lastLine!"=="0" (
    REM call with filename as parameter:
    call :dothis "%%~a"
  ) else (
    echo %%a nothing to do
  )
)
goto :eof

:dothis
REM execute second program with filename as parameter:
myProgram2.exe %1
goto :eof
```

Please try and report back

Comment: still not able to to execute program2. only run the program 1

Comment: insert a `echo -!lastline!-` just before `if "!lastLine" =="0"` and report it's exact output please

Comment: This is the output C:\Desktop>(
REM get last line [reference filename with 1.jpg]
 for /F %b in ('C:\CoordinatesBandedArrow.exe -a -b -c "1.jpg"') do set lastLine=%b
 REM check for "0":
 echo -!lastline!
 if "!lastLine!" == "0" (
REM call with filename as parameter:
 call :dothis "1.jpg"
)  else (echo 1.jpg nothing to do )
) Still not able to run second program

Comment: what's the output of `echo -!lastline!-`? Should be `-0-` or `-1-` at best.

Comment: thats the problem .its nothing

Comment: output

C:\Desktop>(
REM get last line [reference filename with 1.jpg]
 for /F %b in ('C:\CoordinatesBandedArrow.exe -a -b -c "1.jpg"') do set lastLine=%b
 REM check for "0":
 echo -!lastline!-
 if "!lastLine!" == "0" (
REM call with filename as parameter:
 call :dothis "1.jpg"
)  else (echo 1.jpg nothing to do )
)

Comment: I dont understand where is the problem. Any help?